# How to increment value of a existing redis hash field using increment()?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to increment the value of a hash which is already present in the Redis. I am using increment() function of a Redis template in following way.

```
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

String subscriptionKey = "sge:subscription:" + subscriber.getSubscriptionUid();
Object fieldKey = new String("deliveredCount");
redisTemplate.opsForHash().increment(subscriptionKey, fieldKey, 1);
```

Where deliveredCound field is defined in domain class as follows:

```
@JsonProperty("delivered_count")
    private Integer deliveredCount = 0;
```

Now the issue is Redis is able to increment the value but it is not able to detect that the field key is already present. As it is not able to find the existing field key, it is creating a new field in Redis.

For example:

[image: This is how it is adding the keys which should not happen as the field key deliveredCount already present]

What is wrong I am doing here? Appreciate the help :)

Comment: What does the entry look like in Redis when you `HGETALL` the key on the command line, and how did it get added in first place. Spring Data Redis does nothing more than hand over `key`, `field` and `increment` to Redis via `HINCRBY` which seems to work according to what is shown above.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl It's working fine through the command line. I ran following command:
HINCRBY sge:subscription:2d9b99f4-20e9-43c1-83ad-ef15ee85cb09 deliveredCount 1

And then this:
hgetall sge:subscription:2d9b99f4-20e9-43c1-83ad-ef15ee85cb09

I found that count is getting updated through command line but it seems through java code it is not working.
It is treating deliveredCount as "deliveredCount" and adding this new field "deliveredCount " but this should not happen.

Comment: do you have an example reproducing the error that I can run?